# Run shell command and get PID created process

Tags: c++, linux, process

I have this code which runs the command I give to it:

```
pid_t Utils::RunCommand(std::string cmd, int * infp, int * outfp)
{
std::cout << cmd << std::endl;
const char* command = cmd.c_str();
int p_stdin[2];
int p_stdout[2];
pid_t pid;

if (pipe(p_stdin) == -1)
    return -1;

if (pipe(p_stdout) == -1) {
    close(p_stdin[0]);
    close(p_stdin[1]);
    return -1;
}

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
    close(p_stdin[0]);
    close(p_stdin[1]);
    close(p_stdout[0]);
    close(p_stdout[1]);
    return pid;
}
else if (pid == 0) {
    close(p_stdin[1]);
    dup2(p_stdin[0], 0);
    close(p_stdout[0]);
    dup2(p_stdout[1], 1);
    dup2(::open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY), 2);
    /// Close all other descriptors for the safety sake.
    for (int i = 3; i < 4096; ++i)
        ::close(i);

    setsid();
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
    _exit(1);
}

close(p_stdin[0]);
close(p_stdout[1]);

if (infp == NULL) {
    close(p_stdin[1]);
}
else {
    *infp = p_stdin[1];
}

if (outfp == NULL) {
    close(p_stdout[0]);
}
else {
    *outfp = p_stdout[0];
}

return pid; }
```

The problem I am having with this code is the returned process ID is for the shell process that runs my command which prevents me from checking if the command I ran is still running. How can I either modify this function to instead return to me the created process or find the child's PID from the parent PID?

Comment: Why do you need to start a shell to run the command? Why can't you run the command *directly* with `exec`?

Comment: As for the problem of pids, the shell `/bin/sh` will in turn fork a new process to run the command, which is why you don't have the pid of the command itself. But why do you need to monitor the pid of the command itself? The shell you `exec` will not exit until the command is done, so why not simply `wait` for the child process running the shell (if you don't want to run the command directly)?

Comment: My application will accept arbitrary shell commands as user input that will not be compatible with a direct `exec` call

Comment: I also would like to be able to arbitrarily decide when to kill my process and see if it has already ended by itself.

Comment: When you say "arbitrary" you also mean e.g. `for` or other commands "built-in" into the shell? You know that running arbitrary commands is quite a big risk security-wise? Where's the "commands" coming from? Is the "commands" you call filtered someway? Placed in a sandbox?

Comment: I am using this to manage the execution and parameters of local perl scripts so security would not be an issue. Could this be done by using the mentioned `exec` call?

Comment: If the Perl scripts are made executable and have the proper she-bang (i.e. the shell can call the scripts as commands) then yes you can execute them directly with `execl`. As in `execl("/path/to/script.pl", "script.pl", "other", "argument", NULL);`